# Script timeout being ignored by VB DLL

Tags: vb6, asp-classic, com+

Very briefly: I'm having an issue with ensuring that VB DLLs honour the timeouts set in IIS and ASP.

A site I work on uses a number of home-rolled DLLs and their methods could, potentially, run for longer than a web user is willing to wait.  If the visitor presses Escape or closes their browser then the process naturally continues on the server, sucking up CPU time and memory.

In my ASP I have set server.scriptTimeout to a low number (let's say 10 seconds) and I've done the same thing in IIS for the whole web app (because I know server.scriptTimeout is ignored if it is lower than the IIS timeout).

If I run my ASP page with nothing in it but a loop that runs a few million times then the script *does* time out properly ie after 10 seconds.  However, if I move that loop into a very simple DLL (which is then registered properly with COM+) then my script runs for about 210 seconds before timing out.

So my question is: how can I make the script time out as I have asked it to?

Comment: This is probably going to impact on me sometime, so I'll ask a couple of questions: Can the timeout value be passed to the DLL? Do you have a DoEvents in the body of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the ASP engine passes control to the DLL when it makes the call to a method in a DLL. Until the method returns, ASP is not actually calling the shots, once the call returns, it realized that the time has exceeded and ends the script execution.